# How to rotate the Matplotlib table header to certain degree?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a table rendered with matplotlib as shown below

[image: Table]

But, I am having difficulties in rotating the table header to, say 45 degree.

May I know how can I fix this?

```
import six

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def render_mpl_table (data, col_width=1.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=8,
                      header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                      bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                      ax=None, **kwargs):
if ax is None:
    size = (np.array (data.shape [::-1]) + np.array ([0, 1])) * np.array ([col_width, row_height])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots (figsize=size)
    ax.axis ('off')

mpl_table = ax.table (cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

mpl_table.auto_set_font_size (False)
mpl_table.set_fontsize (font_size)

for k, cell in six.iteritems (mpl_table._cells):
    cell.set_edgecolor (edge_color)
    if k [0] == 0 or k [1] < header_columns:
        cell.set_text_props (weight='bold', color='w')
        cell.set_facecolor (header_color)
    else:
        cell.set_facecolor (row_colors [k [0] % len (row_colors)])
return ax


df = pd.DataFrame ({'Label': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
                    'Month': ['Type  1', 'Type  1', 'Type 2', 'Type 2', 'Type 3',
                              'Type  1', 'Type 3', 'Type  1', 'Type 2'],
                    'Activity': ['cc', 'cc', 'tt', 'cc', 'tt', 'tt', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', ]})
tt = pd.crosstab (index=[df ['Activity']], columns=[df ['Label'], df ['Month']], margins=True)


tab_me = render_mpl_table (tt, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
plt.show ()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003603/how-can-i-rotate-column-titles-in-pyplot-table

Comment: Hi @pecey, I have comb the link you provided before I post this OP. But nothing similar/solution can be found there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cell.get_text().set_rotation(45)` when you set your header [after `cell.set_facecolor (header_color)`] to rotate the text. But you would need to adjust the height of the header cell accordingly. For that you can use `cell.set_height(1)`.